Use Column A if its Current Month to solve for X, And Use last month's column X for the next months column X
You're help will be greatly appreciated!! I'm not really sure if this is possible in PBI.
So I've been trying to figure this out for the past two days and I can't either search for the current keyword online. I've tested a couple of approaches but it always filters to the current month instead of using the previous month when I'm putting it in a Matrix table.
Chart:
I have a Matrix Table which have Materials on Rows, Months on Columns and different Measures on Values.
Problematic Measure:
I am trying to get the monthly Est. Ending Inventory which has the formula of
If Current Month:
Stocks on Hand - (Forecast - Sales) + Incoming Shipments
For the Next Months
Previous Months Est Ending Inventory - Forecast + Shipment
Meaning
If I'm solving for June, I'll have
Est End Invty = June's SOH - (June's Forecast + June's Sales) + June's Incoming Ships
If I'm going to solve for July
June's Est End Invty - July's Forecast + July's incoming Ships
If for Aug
July's Est End Invty - Aug'sForecast + Aug's incoming Ships
and so on.....
What is currently happening is, if I put the measure in the matrix, I'm not getting the previous month's est end
Here's my current formula
Est. End Invy =
Measure = 
    var adjustedDate = IF(MONTH(TODAY()) > 3, MONTH(TODAY()) -3, MONTH(TODAY()) +  9)
    VAR currentMonth = 
        CALCULATE(
            MAX( 0 , [Total Stocks on Hand] - ABS ([Total Sales Outlook] - [Total Sales] ) + [Total Incoming Shipment] ),
        FILTER (
            ALLSELECTED(DIM_CALENDAR_SALES),
            DIM_CALENDAR_SALES[FSDATE] = MAX(DIM_CALENDAR_SALES[FSDATE])))
        
    VAR next = 
            MAX( 0, currentMonth - [Total Sales Outlook] + [Total Incoming Shipment] )

    VAR nextMonths =
            MAX( 0, next - [Total Sales Outlook] + [Total Incoming Shipment] )

        VAR result =
        IF(MONTH(MAX(DIM_CALENDAR_SALES[FSDATE])) = adjustedDate, currentMonth,
            IF(DATEDIFF(MAX(DIM_CALENDAR_SALES[FSDATE]), adjustedDate, MONTH) = 1 , next,
        nextMonths))
        
    RETURN
        result


Can you share input data ? model ?
